# Are there better tires for heavy riders?

Tags: tire, upgrades, heavy

I have upgraded the backwheel on my hybrid bike to one suitable for a 285 pound rider. Are there tires suited for 285 pound (130 kg) riders?

Comment: How heavy? I suggest looking at tyres for touring and/or tandem use. I think this has been covered in some detail here before.

Comment: A touring tire with the largest diameter your bicycle will take.

Comment: I think you will require snow/ice studded tyres more, given this fatbike was for winter riding.

Comment: Acknowledged I edited heavy and substituted 285 pounds. These tires are for my Yorkville hybrid which is ridden three seasons. The fatbike didn't work out.

Comment: Given @Criggie's comment about winter use, I'd still stick with the marathon series: [the 26x2.0](https://www.schwalbe.com/en/spike-reader/marathon-winter.html) for example, is rated to a load of 105kg per tyre (230lbs).  That should be plenty even with around 2/3 your weight on the back wheel (just don't do any wheelies!) This doesn't really change things compared to the linked question

Answer (score 2):

I would go as wide as your frame and fork will allow. The increased volume will support the weight better than a skinnier tire at higher pressure.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested I am going with touring tires for my Norco hybrid.
A Schwalbé Marathon supreme on the back and a Schwalbé Marathon supreme on the front.

Answer (score -1):

My suggestions would be go for the broader ones with advanced polymer (synthesised ones) with larger tread blocks for a better grip on the roads.

Comment: The usual thought is that tread does nothing on a plain flat road.  Tread with blocks actively decreases the road contact surface area while increasing the pressure on the blocks, and larger (ie taller) blocks contribute to sideways squirm when cornering.  Even siping on the tyre does nothing because a bike tyre is a lot thinner+rounder than a car tyre and cannot aquaplane at human speeds.